# Same Message is getting produced/consumed more than once in a multi-cluster environment

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

Please find below given configuration for kafka consumer and kafka producer in two servers

Consumer (C):

```
<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="inAdapter"
    channel="fromKafka"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    key-decoder="kafkaKeyDecoder"
    payload-decoder="kafkaDecoder"                              
    topics="sample_intopic"
    offset-manager="offsetManager"
/>
```

Producer (P):

```
<int-kafka:producer-context id="producerContext" producer-properties="producerProperties">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
    <int-kafka:producer-configuration
        broker-list="${kafka.producer.config.brokerList}"
        topic="headers['topic']"
        key-class-type="java.lang.String"
        value-class-type="com.XX.XX.vo.MesgeContentVO"
        value-encoder="kafkaEncoder"
        key-encoder="kafkaKeyEncoder"
        compression-type="none"
     />
     </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
     </int-kafka:producer-context>
 />
```

I am deploying the same kafka consumer (C) and kafka producer (P) in server 1 and server 2 connecting to the same kafka broker.

Whenever I am producing one message in server 1 then it is getting consumed four times (getting 4 messages). My Requirement is that produced message should be consumed only once.

What is happenning here is: let's say, message sent by calling applicaton.send(message);

```
            P,C                   P,C
            server s1           server s2
```

Therefore,both P are acting as a producer and each one of them passing it to the consumer of its own and other consumer, so,

```
             P in s1 sending to -->C in s1 and C in s2
             P in s2 sending to-->C  in s2 and C in S1
```

Therefore 1 message is produced 2 times and consumed 4 times.

I would like to know, is there any way we can restrict it and once the message gets produced/consumed, if it is coming 2nd time to the same producer/consumer we can uniquely identify it and avoid producing/consuming it in above configuration.

Comment: It looks like you are using a very old version of spring-integration-kafka and kafka 0.8.x.x; I suggest you upgrade to a more recent version 2.1 uses kafka 0.10.x.x, 2.0 uses kafka 0.9.x.x; you can set a group id and the broker will handle partition assignment to consumers. There's nothing kafka (or spring) can do to help if you send a message twice from different producers.

Comment: Thanks Gary,

However in this scenario,it is not the  different producer neither the message sent twice.Message is sent only once but the same producer(P) code is deployed twice i.e in 2 instances of the server.
What i understand is we can't uniquely identify the message for duplicacy(by message id etc) if the same message is fed in the producer(P) multiple times.is that's so?

Comment: I don't understand why both producers are sending the **same** message.